# checkvalidity not detecting wrong value

Tags: javascript, html

In this form input

```
<textarea name="descripcion" rows="4" maxlength="4000" required rows="4"
    class="small-12 align-middle text-right"
    placeholder="Description" pattern=".*\S+.*">
</textarea>
```

I'm trying to detec that the value is not an empty space with

```
e.checkValidity()
```

e is the textarea snd this is working correct , but the text of the textarea its an empty space and `e.checkValidity()` returning a `true` value

Comment: Hello, I'm a little confused, If I'm not wrong you want to know whether the text area is empty or not?

Comment: No, I dont know why if the value of the text area is " " `e.checkValidity` is returning true if  `pattern=".*\S+.*"`  is set